# Loading React hooks using dynamic imports?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-hooks

I'm using a few third-party React hook libraries that aren't required for the initial render. E.g. `react-use-gesture`, `react-spring`, and `react-hook-form`. They all provide interactivity, which can wait until after the UI is rendered. I want to dynamically load these using Webpack's codesplitting (i.e. `import()`) after I render my component.

However, I can't stub out a React hook because it's essentially a conditional hook, which React doesn't support.

The 2 solutions that I can think of are:

1. Somehow extract the hook into a component and use composition
2. Force React to reconstruct a component after the hook loads

Both solutions seem hacky and it's likely that future engineers will mess it up. Are there better solutions for this?

Comment: As you mentioned yourself, conditionally importing hooks breaks the first rule of React hooks. This is because the behaviour is unpredictable on successive renders and I cannot see how you would be able to achieve your goal. Looking at `react-hook-form` as an example, you would not have access to `handleSubmit` which is required on each render.

Explanation: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation

Comment: I did this with a hook using functionality from framer-motion before. I essentially exposed what should be imported from framer-motion, a state which tells the hook user if the module is ready, and a function to load framer-motion module. My component will check if the module is ready or not before using the module exposed from the hook. It's not exactly a robust solution, and it requires you to manually handle the cases when the module isn't ready yet.

Comment: We use the first method all the time, it's so straightforward. You simply render a component conditionally which has the hook at its top level.

Comment: What you are talking about sounds like something I've heard called the sidecar pattern https://github.com/theKashey/use-sidecar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you say it, there are two ways to go about using lazy loaded hooks:

1. Load library in a Parent Component, conditionally render Component using library when available

Something along the lines of

```js
let lib
const loadLib = () => {...}

const Component = () => {
  const {...hooks} = lib
  ...
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => loadComponent().then(() => setLoaded(true)), [])
  return loaded && <Component/>
}
```

This method is indeed a little hacky and a lot of manual work for each library

2. Start loading a component using the hook, fail, reconstruct the component when the hook is loaded

This can be streamlined with the help of **React.Suspense**

```js
<Suspense fallback={"Loading..."}>
  <ComponentWithLazyHook/>
</Suspense>
```

Suspense works similar to Error Boundary like follows:

1. Component throws a Promise during rendering (via **React.lazy** or manually)
2. Suspense catches that Promise and renders Fallback
3. Promise resolves
4. Suspense re-renders the component

This way is likely to get more popular when [**Suspense for Data Fetching**](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) matures from experimental phase.

But for our purposes of loading a library once, and likely caching the result, a simple implementation of data fetching can do the trick

```
const cache = {}
const errorsCache = {}
// <Suspense> catches the thrown promise
// and rerenders children when promise resolves
export const useSuspense = (importPromise, cacheKey) => {
  const cachedModule = cache[cacheKey]
  // already loaded previously
  if (cachedModule) return cachedModule

  //prevents import() loop on failed imports
  if (errorsCache[cacheKey]) throw errorsCache[cacheKey]

  // gets caught by Suspense
  throw importPromise
    .then((mod) => (cache[cacheKey] = mod))
    .catch((err) => {
      errorsCache[cacheKey] = err
    })
};

const SuspendedComp = () => {
  const { useForm } = useSuspense(import("react-hook-form"), "react-hook-form")
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm()
  ...
}

...

<Suspense fallback={null}>
  <SuspendedComp/>
</Suspense>
```

You can see a sample implementation [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-dhawan-noxj2?file=/src/App.tsx:1245-1409).

**Edit:**

As I was writing the example in codesandbox, it completely escaped me that dependency resolution will behave differently than locally in webpack.

Webpack `import()` [can't handle completely dynamic paths](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import) like `import(importPath)`. It must have `import('react-hook-form')` somewhere statically, to create a chunk at build time.

So we must write `import('react-hook-form')` ourselves and also provide the `importPath = 'react-hook-form'` to use as a cache key.

I updated the codesanbox example to one that works with webpack, the old example, which won't work locally, can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-dawn-scxs0?file=/src/App.tsx:1036-1202)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered stubbing the hooks? We used something similar to async load a large lib, but it was not a hook, so YMMV.

```
// init with stub
let _useDrag = () => undefined;

// load the actual implementation asynchronously
import('react-use-gesture').then(({useDrag}) => _useDrag = useDrag);

export asyncUseDrag = (cb) => _useDrag(cb)
```